# Redundant syntax with `enum class`

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a templated class, where I use an `enum class` as a template parameter. Here's a full (trivial) example:

```
enum class AnimalType { Dog, Cat, Hamster };

template <AnimalType>
class Animal {
public:
  std::string speak();
};

template <>
std::string Animal<AnimalType::Dog>::speak() {
  return "Woof";
}

template <>
std::string Animal<AnimalType::Cat>::speak() {
  return "Meow";
}

template <>
std::string Animal<AnimalType::Hamster>::speak() {
  return "Iä! Iä! Cthulhu fhtagn!";
}

int main() {
  Animal<AnimalType::Dog> dog;
  Animal<AnimalType::Cat> cat;
  Animal<AnimalType::Hamster> hamster;

  cout << dog.speak() << endl << cat.speak() << endl << hamster.speak() << endl;
}
```

Is there a way of avoiding the verbose and redundant `Animal<AnimalType::Hamster>` syntax?

Comment: You can use `typedef` to define shorter aliases for long-winded class names, that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 1):

Put the class and its `enum class` into a namespace where they can have brief names:

```
namespace Animal {

enum class Type { Dog, Cat, Hamster };

template <Type>
class Animal {
public:
  std::string speak();
};

template <>
std::string Animal<Type::Dog>::speak() {
  return "Woof";
}

… etc

} // namespace Animal
```

Then in a narrower scope use a `using` statement:

```
int main(){
  using Animal::Animal;
  using Animal::Type; // error
  Animal<Type::Dog> dog;
  Animal<Type::Cat> cat;
  … etc
}
```

If the class and namespace have the same name, you can't write `using Animal::Type;` because it's ambiguous. But you can use the global scope symbol to explicitly show you're taking about the namespace:

```
int main(){
  using ::Animal::Animal;
  using ::Animal::Type; // ok
  Animal<Type::Dog> dog; 
  … etc
}
```

Comment: Not sure the addition of the using statement is really less verbose and worth the loss of simplicity that your original version provided :)